# Errors installing R-INLA

Tags: r, installation, r-inla

I have a problem. I am writing on my masterthesis and for my research question I have to use R-INLA.
I tried to install the INLA-Package several times but there is an Error and it doesn't work.

https://www.r-inla.org/download-install
When I try to install INLA like it is shown in the link, it doesn't work. I get some warnings, e.g.

"dependencies 'graph', 'Rgraphviz' are not available"
or, second example:
"Warning (...) file link "CRS"/"CRSargs" in packags "sp"/"rgdal" does not exist"

How can I deal with that? What can I do to solve this problems? I have no other choice, my professor wants me to use R-INLA for my thesis. I hope someone can help me, I am very desperate, tried so much but the problem still exists. Thank You!

Comment: The message says that `graph` and `Rgraphviz` are not available. Have you tried `install.packages(c("graph", "Rgraphviz"))`?

Comment: Yes I tried, but that also doesn't work. Both packages are not available for my version of R

Comment: *That* is your problem, not R-INLA. Neither of those packages appear to be on CRAN, one stating that it has been migrated to bioconductor. Are you certain that your `repos=` setting is correct to be able to install from their repo?

Comment: did you look at the third paragraph/code box of the installation instructions? `if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("BiocManager") };
BiocManager::install(c("graph", "Rgraphviz"), dep=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but there is another problem: Matrix, rgdal and tibble have to be installed and installation of tibble failed